# float placement for listings causes warnings in make4ht

Tags: floats, listings, make4ht

The following examples compiles but creates warnings just when the `float` parameter is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[float, language=tex, label=lst-enum, caption={Enumerated list.}]
\begin{enumerate}
\item example 1
\item example 2
\item example 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with `make4ht` and the warning generated are:

```
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of article.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/figure) [char=1997]
```

Is there something wrong or a way to avoid these warnings? Could it lead to a crash in a more complex example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `domfilter` error means that the generated HTML file is not valid and DOM processing failed. This is a serious issue, as `make4ht` uses it to fix common errors in the generated HTML file.

The problem is that TeX4ht configuration for `lstlisting` environment inserts '`tags around it's content, but the`float`option inserts`` tag at the wrong place.

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
    \gHAdvance\listingN by 1
    \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
    \gdef\start:LstLn{%
       \HCode{<div class="lstlisting" id="listing-\listingN">}%
       \gdef\start:LstLn{\:nbsp%
\HCode{<br />\Hnewline}}}
    \bgroup
\pend:def\lst@DeInit{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \HCode{</div>}}
       \Configure{listings}
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}
         {\start:LstLn \HCode{<span class="label">}}
         {\HCode{</span>}}%
   }
   {\egroup\par
    }
   {} {}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

It is a modified version from TeX4ht sources, the difference is that it patches the `\lst@DeInit` macro to insert the closing tag for `</div>` before `</figure>`, in order to produce the correct HTML structure.

Comment: So this a temporary patch while it is not fixed in newer versions of ```make4ht```, right?

Comment: @LEo yes. I've already fixed that in TeX4ht sources, so it should be available soon in TL.