# how to make tex4ht work with listings styles for only basic decoration? (frame and background coloring)?

Tags: listings, tex4ht

This is tex4ht only issue.

There is a good answer in [How to add frame and background color with listing when used with text4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637695/how-to-add-frame-and-background-color-with-listing-when-used-with-text4ht) That shows how to make tex4ht put frame and background color when using `listings` package with `\lstset{...}` and then `\begin{lstlisting}`

But this solution did not work when using `listings` styles.  A small example will make this clear.  This MWE works, since it uses `\lstset{...}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,255,226}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
breaklines=true,
backgroundcolor=\color{bg},
language=,
frame = single,
frameround=tttt,
rulecolor=\color{gray}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
          This is a test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `make4ht  -ulm default -a debug -c ./my.cfg foo.tex "mathjax,htm"`

Gives this HTML (the .cfg file used above is given at the bottom. It is the same from the answer in the link above)

[image]

All is well. But since I have many languages, I need to use `\lstdefinestyle` to name the style, and then use `\lstset` with the language name. This way I can use different listing in same latex document, each with named style.

When I did this, now tex4ht no longer adds frame and background color.

Here is the same example above but done using `listings` style environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,255,226}
    
\lstdefinestyle{plainText}{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breaklines=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{bg},
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    language=,
    frame=single,
    frameround=tttt,
    aboveskip=12pt,belowskip=12pt
}

\lstnewenvironment{plainTextEnv}{%
  \lstset{style=plainText}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{plainTextEnv}
This is a test
\end{plainTextEnv}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using same command gives

[image]

So the decorations are not used. I think this is because the .cfg is only looking for `lstlisting` and `lstinputlisting` hooks and not for `lstnewenvironment`

Is it possible to make the .cfg also work for the above setup? Otherwise, I will have to add `\ifdefined\HCode` around each listing which makes the code hard to read.

### Appendix

Here is the .cfg used

```
%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637695/how-to-add-frame-and-background-color-with-listing-when-used-with-text4ht
%code thanks to michal.h21 

\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{%
\bgroup%
  % handle backround color and border in listings
  \ifx\lst@fillcolor\@empty\else%
    \lst@fillcolor%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\html@fillcolor%
    \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@fillcolor{HTML}\html@fillcolor%
    \Css{\#listing-\listingN{background-color:\#\html@fillcolor;}}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\lst@rulecolor\@empty\else%
    \lst@rulecolor%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\html@rulecolor%
    \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@rulecolor{HTML}\html@rulecolor%
    \Css{\#listing-\listingN{border: 1px solid \#\html@rulecolor;}}%
  \fi%
\egroup%
}
\Configure{lstinputlisting}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
    \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
    \gHAdvance\listingN by 1%
    \HCode{<pre class="lstinputlisting" id="listing-\listingN">}%
    \bgroup\ttfamily%\special{t4ht@(}%
       \Configure{listings}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {\HCode{\Hnewline<span class="label">}}%
         {\HCode{</span>}}%
   }
   {%\special{t4ht@)}
    \egroup%
    \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP  \HCode{</pre>}\par}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX4ht supports custom Listings environments, but the default configuration don't add numeric ID to the generated HTML, so the CSS instructions for borders and background color don't take an effect. It should be fixed with this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
    \Configure{lstinline}
   {\HCode{<code class="lstinline">}\NoFonts}
   {\EndNoFonts\HCode{</code>}}
\Css{code.lstinline{font-family:monospace,monospace;}}
\Log:Note{to ensure proper alignments use
   fixed size fonts (see listings.dtx)}
\HAssign\listingN=0
\HAssign\listings:Depth = 0
\Configure{listings}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
   \gdef\start:LstLn{}%
    {\everypar{}\leavevmode}\HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
     \ifnum \listings:Depth=0 \HCode{<pre class="listings" id="listing-\listingN">}\else
                              \HCode{<span class="listings-nested" id="listing-\listingN">}\fi
     \gHAdvance\listings:Depth by 1
   }
   {\gHAdvance\listings:Depth by -1
    \ifnum \listings:Depth=0 \HCode{</pre>}\else
                             \HCode{</span>}\fi
   }
   {\start:LstLn%\:nbsp%
   \gdef\start:LstLn{\HCode{\Hnewline}}%
\HCode{<span class="label">}}%
   {\HCode{</span>}}%
\Configure{listings-init}{\ttfamily\special{t4ht@(}}{\special{t4ht@)}}
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
    %\gHAdvance\listingN by 1
    \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
    \gdef\start:LstLn{%
       \HCode{<pre class="lstlisting" id="listing-\listingN">}%
       \gdef\start:LstLn{\HCode{\Hnewline}}}
    \bgroup%
    % we put the closing </div> here in order to support floating listings
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615703/2891
    \pend:def\lst@DeInit{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</pre>}}%
       \Configure{listings}
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}
         {\start:LstLn \HCode{<span class="label">}}
         {\HCode{</span>}}%
   }
   {\egroup\par}
   {} {}
\Css{.lstlisting .label{margin-right:0.5em; }}
\Css{pre.lstlisting{font-family: monospace,monospace; white-space: pre-wrap;
                    margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:0.5em;
                   }}
\Configure{lstinputlisting}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
    \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
    \gdef\start:LstLn{\gdef\start:LstLn{\HCode{\Hnewline}}}% ignore first newline, to prevent spurious line
    \HCode{<pre class="lstinputlisting" id="listing-\listingN">}%
    \bgroup\ttfamily%\special{t4ht@(}%
       \Configure{listings}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}%
         {\start:LstLn \HCode{<span class="label">}}%
         {\HCode{</span>}}%
   }
   {%\special{t4ht@)}
    \egroup%
    \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP  \HCode{</pre>}\par}%
\Css{pre.lstinputlisting{
   font-family: monospace,monospace;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}}
\Css{.lstinputlisting .label{margin-right:0.5em;}}
\lst@AddToHook{PostOutput}{\HCode{</span>}}%

\lst@AddToHook{OutputBox}{%
  % get current color in the CSS form
  \extractcolorspec{.}\html@color%
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@color{HTML}\html@color%
  \HCode{<span style="color:\#\html@color">}}% init
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{%
\gHAdvance\listingN by 1%
\bgroup%
  % handle backround color and border in listings
  \ifx\lst@fillcolor\@empty\else%
    \lst@fillcolor%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\html@fillcolor%
    \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@fillcolor{HTML}\html@fillcolor%
    \Css{\#listing-\listingN{background-color:\#\html@fillcolor;}}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\lst@rulecolor\@empty\else%
    \lst@rulecolor%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\html@rulecolor%
    \expandafter\convertcolorspec\html@rulecolor{HTML}\html@rulecolor%
    \Css{\#listing-\listingN{border: 1px solid \#\html@rulecolor;}}%
  \fi%
\egroup%
}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result for your sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael.   I am testing it and found it removes newlines from the input. For example, if I have `\begin{plainTextEnv}
This is line 1
   This is line 2
\end{plainTextEnv}` (but each on separate line in the latex file , hard to show here but here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOzER.png)), and everything the same, and using your above .cfg, I see the HTML output all one line.  I hope this is easy to fix.   Here is screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Gtb.png)

Comment: @Nasser I see. Try the updated answer. It unfortunately inserts extra line at the end of listings, because it cannot detect an empty line.

Comment: This worked Great. Having an extra empty line at end of listing is no problem at all. Thanks again for all support and help.